# Avoid desktop notification for new mail if Thunderbird thinks it is spam

Tags: thunderbird, notification

With a current combination of Thunderbird (91.7) and Ubuntu 18.04, can Thunderbird be configured to not show desktop notifications when it decided that a new mail is spam?

Currently is shows a desktop notification for each new mail just fine, but it would be great to suppress it for mail it classifies as spam.

Comment: thunderbird v91 => settings => incoming e-mail-messages